# How can I get two paragraph tags on the same line that have different classes?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a login, Password and Submit all on the same line.

```html
<p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"><input type="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p><p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?  This is not hard to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `span` to add different classes within one paragraph tag

For example:

```
<p><span class="1">First Item</span> <span class="2">Second Item</span></p>
```

however, it sounds like you are looking to use `input` fields in a `form` that needs to submit data. In this case all you have to do is this:
https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/25012/

Answer (score 1):

You can make HTML elements in-inline (on the same line) by adding the ***display*** css attribute:

```
display:inline-block;
```

< input > elements default to inline-block display. But < p > elements default to block display; which means they have a break-line after the element.

However, given that you seem to be new to HTML and CSS, I would highly suggest you check out [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It's a framework that makes website styling and templates easier. This is why in your source the < p > surrounding the two inputs breaks into a new line before the submit input is rendered.

See this snippet from [their documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) of how to make an in-line login form. Run this snippet in *full page* mode to see how it's works in-line.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been meaning to learn bootstrap. With everyone having an opinion on which direction you should go in after using HTML CSS I've felt pulled in all sorts of directions (Bootstrap, Node, Angular, etc).